# How to access RStudio-server remotely?

Tags: r, rstudio-server, hortonworks-sandbox

I've installed Rstudio-server in Hortonworks sandbox (Azure).
I'm sure that rserver is running properly, I verified it by running '$ sudo rstudio-server status'.
But, When I tried to access RStudio through the URL:IP-Add:8787, nothing is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't embed images yet, and can only link 2. Let me know if my instructions are not clear.

On your Azure dashboard, go to *All Resources* on your menu to the left. 
Find the *Network Resource Group* for your Hortonworks sandbox virtual machine. If you only have a few VMs it should be easy to find, the default seems to be the VM name.
[Network Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WY9O.png)

Open the NSG, On the overview tab that pops up, you will see your firewall security rules, both inbound and outbound. You need to add a new inbound security rule for port 8787
[Icons for firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny3j5.png)
Click on the 2 icons in the picture above. You will give a name to the rule (say Rstudio Server)
Then change the Port Range to 8787, hit *OK*. If you have a static IP address that you will be accessing from then you will want to refine this rule to only allow traffic from your network, but for testing you can allow traffic from any source.

You should then see your new rule in the list of Inbound security rules.

Try to access yourip:8787. You should be able to see the Rstudio login page.